# How to use an RGB normal map in the Displace modifier

Tags: normal-map, displacement

I have a model which was created for a game engine. It uses the usual RGB normal format (most pixels are just under $(.5, .5, 1)$ for some normal maps in the form of PNG images.

I'd like to use these normal maps and the low-poly geometry to approximate the original high-poly geometry. I know I need to use the subdivision or multires modifers, followed by a displace modifier, but what settings should I use to apply this kind of normal map in the displace modifier?

So far in experimenting I've set "direction" to "RGB to XYZ" and "texture co-ordinates" to "UV", but I'm not sure what the correct values for "space", "midlevel", and "strength" should be, nor if there's anything I need to change in the texture block.

Other questions on this subject seem to be about using greyscale bump maps for displacement, or about the (more common) reverse process of baking a high-poly mesh into a normal map.